# PHP: Get parameter from encoded url

Tags: php

I have this url:

```
/?goto=%2Fr%2Faccount%2Findex%2Ecfm%3Fsite_id%3D87211
```

How can I `GET` site_id from this url?

Comment: What do you mean by "have this url"? Do you have that text in a string variable, or is that the URL used to reach your PHP script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know your url's will always be in this structure, you can parse it out with RegEx like so:

```
$url = '/?goto=%2Fr%2Faccount%2Findex%2Ecfm%3Fsite_id%3D87211';
preg_match('/site_id\%3D(\d+)/', $url, $matches);
$siteId = $matches[1];
```

It's searching for anything that matches `site_id%3D` and the numeric value that follows that.

Comment: $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; works, thanks!

Comment: That's pretty horrible code. `\%` is redundant because `%` is not a regex metacharacter. It returns the wrong string if another query parameter ends with `xyz_size_id` (or if the path contains `site_id=`). It also assumes the site_id consists of digits only, and that none of the digits are url-encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Check this way,

```
  <?php
  $abc ="/?goto=%2Fr%2Faccount%2Findex%2Ecfm%3Fsite_id%3D87211";

  $test = parse_url($abc);
  $test = urldecode($test["query"]);

  $url = parse_url($test);    
  parse_str($url['query'], $param);
  print_r($param["site_id"]);

  ?>
```

Check your output here :https://eval.in/621360

Answer (score 0):

Try [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on `$_GET['goto']`.

```
parse_str(parse_url($_GET['goto'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
$site_id = $params['site_id'];
```

Comment: I'd really like to know why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: Probably because I misinterpreted that he had only a query string inside $_GET['goto'], so I forgot to add a parse_url to it to extract only the query string. (Just fixed it)

Answer (score -1):

Try using [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php/) in URL function

Comment: What "URL function"?

Answer (score -1):

by using $_GET['goto'] you will get following url :

```
/r/account/index.cfm?site_id=87211
```

Try this

```
    $uri = $_GET['goto'];
    $site = explode("=", $uri);
    echo $site[1];
```